# How to open a particular port in ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, port-forwarding

My SoulSeek client Nicotine+ checks my open ports during initial configuration and promts that the one port number it needs is closed, cutting me off frmo about 50% of the users. Is there anyway I can open that particular port for the application to use?

RUnning ubuntu desktop 13.04. I have not manually installed any firewalls, but not sure if its included in the default installation.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu Desktop or Server?  Are running any Firewall?

Comment: Desktop (Trusty) and no additional firewall installed

Answer (score 7):

Run this on the commandline; it should solve issue: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

To do a specific port:

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p <tcp OR udp> <--dport OR --sport> <port> -j ACCEPT`

`INPUT` is the chain for incoming traffic. 
`-p` is protocol (either `tcp` or `udp`
`--dport` or `--sport` specify allowing for destination or source port.
`-j` is "jump" and its where you `ACCEPT`, `REJECT`, or `DROP` the packet(s)

Details on `iptables` can be found by reading the man page. Since you're a beginner you'll probably find this useful: http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO//packet-filtering-HOWTO.html

Comment: @J Moore: Thanks, but where do I put in the port number? Also would help if you could put in a one liner about what these arguments are for?

Comment: I tried the methods above, and though I think they should work, the client port-checking page:  http://tools.slsknet.org/porttest.php?port=2234  always shows that the port is CLOSED. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install at least one firewall, because it's not installed in default installation on ubuntu.

for 32 bits 
 - [Firestarter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/i386/firestarter/download)
for 64 bits 
 - [Firestarter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/firestarter/download)

- Install and open the firestarter, add the inbound policy with this ip:   0.0.0.0/0  
  *(to allow all ip addresses)*
- Add the ports that you need to open.
- Then click on apply the changes button.

Comment: I don't think this is addressing the matter at all. Also clearly the op has little idea of how to execute what you just put forward.