# Which port do I need to open so that others can connect to my "www" folder?

Tags: server, apache2, lan, websites, php7

I want to follow this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293356/how-to-open-a-particular-port-in-ubuntu#293375), but...

I specifically want to let others access a site on a **LAN** that would be stored in the default "/var/www/html" system folder **AKA 127.0.0.1**

So I guess I just need to know which port should I use, a guess is *port 8080*, anyways I want this question to be here @ AskUbuntu for it's usefulness.

[image: 127.0.0.1]

[image: localhost]

Comment: Typically port 80 is used for http webpages (443 for https). Which port you open will depend on which port is being used by your web server.

Comment: I clearly stated what I want. @amc I only guess I would only need to open a port. It's a guess. IDKWTF

Comment: Have you set up the web server and is it running?

Comment: I think @amc answered correctly...you need to open whichever port(s) for which you configure the web server.  Or pick 2 ports to open on your fw and then configure the server appropriately.

Comment: Once that's done, what's the next step ?

Comment: After you install apache server, the required port (80)  is opened automatically as soon as the web-server starts. You don't need to open any port again.

Comment: If you have the default FW setup and you want to use the most common ports for a Webserver you need to configure apache for port 80 and 443 and open both on the firewall. Like @ankit7540 stated once configured your Ubuntu will listen on those 2 ports once Apache is started.

Comment: Great!, @ankit7540 Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after the user installs apache webserver, the web-server is started **as a service.** With the start of this service the **port 80 (for HTTP traffic) is opened automatically**.

Suggested reading and details about *apache / php / MySQL on Ubuntu* : [ApacheMySQLPHP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

***Important:*** Apache, php, phpmyadmin and MySQL should be properly configured for **a secure working of your website**. Please refer to detailed guides elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to "open a port", you want to setup a web server.

By default web server listens at port 80 for HTTP, or the web server opens that port for you. Your site is stored at a folder, you can call it "www", but that is not "AKA" 127.0.0.1, and if you serve it to other computers, you cannot let your web server listen at 127.0.0.1 only. Furthermore, if the access is restricted to LAN only, security may not be a issue, but keep such security concern in your mind when you setup a server for other to access your files. Please make sure you understand such stuff before continuing.

You can start by installing `apache2` package, and your web server is up and running (The files are stored at `/var/www/html`).

I suggest you Google something like "ubuntu apache php" to find tons of guides on this topic, i.e., to install, configure a web server capable of running PHP sites (possibly including a MySQL server), if you encounter some specific problems during this procedure, ask those questions instead.

TIP: it may be more helpful to add your specific Ubuntu version when Googling, like: "ubuntu 14.04 LTS apache php"

Comment: Well if you can read check out the images in the updates. NO need to be a Techie Grammar Nazi. You're playing nice by putting on cards of security which would only shed light in very complex situations. I didn't ask any of the sort. You know I asked for LAN without any concern about security. When I need security I will go to an appropriate place to get informed about any specific situations.